# How to configure slave node in jenkins with SSH-agent

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh

I was configuring a slave node in Jenkins with SSH Agent but I get the follow error:

```
[10/31/17 15:23:37] [SSH] Checking java version of java
[10/31/17 15:23:37] [SSH] java -version returned 1.8.0_151.
[10/31/17 15:23:37] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[10/31/17 15:23:37] [SSH] Remote file system root /var/jenkins does not exist. W
ill try to create it... java.io.IOException: Could not copy slave.jar into /var/
jenkins on slave at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.copySlaveJar(SSHLaunche
r.java:1152) at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.access$400(SSHLauncher.java
:145) at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:816) at hu
dson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:793) at java.util.con
current.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolEx
ecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoo
lExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread
.java:748) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdir /var/jenkins at hudso
n.plugins.sshslaves.SFTPClient.mkdirs(SFTPClient.java:83) at hudson.plugins.sshs
laves.SSHLauncher.copySlaveJar(SSHLauncher.java:1120) ... 7 more Caused by: com.
trilead.ssh2.SFTPException: Permission denied (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED: The use
r does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.) at com.trilead
.ssh2.SFTPv3Client.expectStatusOKMessage(SFTPv3Client.java:555) at com.trilead.s
sh2.SFTPv3Client.mkdir(SFTPv3Client.java:955) at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SFTPCl
ient.mkdirs(SFTPClient.java:81) ... 8 more
[10/31/17 15:23:37] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[10/31/17 15:23:37] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

How do I configure slave node in jenkins with SSH-agent?

Answer (score 0):

In the slave configuration on the Jenkins Master, adjust the remote root to a existing directory (or a sub-directory of one that the Jenkins user is allowed to write into), or create `/var/jenkins` on the slave machine and allow the Jenkins user to write there.

Answer (score 0):

In according to error message:

> Caused by: com.
>   trilead.ssh2.SFTPException: Permission denied (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED: The use
>   r does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.)

make sure that jenkins user on your slave-node has permissions to create directory /var/jenkins.

1. log in to your slave, Then run: `mkdir /var/jenkins`
2. Then change dir owner to **jenkins**: `chown jenkins /var/jenkins`
3. Re-launch slave agent from master.